# Uploading pdf files in php 5.4 and kcfinder

Tags: php, kcfinder

When i am uploading pdf files in kcfinder (on ckeditor version 4), the pdf files are somehow converted to jpg. On php 5.3 there is no such issue.

I also tried diiferent versions of kcfinder

you can see here
http://enviosh.maozanat.co.il/assets/userfiles/files/3521.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have found a solution to this issue. The problem seems to be that with PHP 5.4 Imagick and Magick Wand. What I did was disabled Imagick, and Magick Wand from the PHP Settings.

Then in KCFinder config file changed line 45 from

```
'imageDriversPriority' => "imagick gmagick gd",
```

to

```
'imageDriversPriority' => "gd",
```

You may get away with just editing the KCFinder config file and leaving the php settings alone. I hope this was helpful.